# R - Evaluating all values in matrix and extracting entire row if condition is met

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to write a function that evaluates each term within a matrix against a condition. If the condition is met for any term, the entire row is added to a second matrix.

(context: I am doing so to compare outliers for all attributes. If any row has outlier data for any attribute (their z-score > 3), then the entire row would be added to the Outlier data matrix)

Please see my code below. I really don't understand why it isn't working.

```
outliers <- matrix()
x <- 1
for(r in nrow(all_z_stats)){
  for(c in ncol(all_z_stats)){
    if(all_z_stats[r,c]>3){
      outliers[x,] <- all_z_stats[r,]
      x <- x + 1
    }}
}
```

Thanks very much in advance for any information or input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data: `all_z_stats <- replicate(20, rnorm(20))`

First, `for r in nrow(all_z_stats)` leads to only one `r` value. Better loop r through all values form 1 to `nrow(all_z_stats)`: `for (r in seq_len(all_z_stats))` = `for (r in 1:nrow(all_z_stats))` (same for `c`)

First improvement:

```
outliers <- matrix(ncol=ncol(all_z_stats)) # Empty matrix with as many cols as outliers matrix
for(r in seq_len(nrow(all_z_stats))){
    if(any(all_z_stats[r, ] > 3)){ # any is useful, try ?any in R console
        outliers <- rbind(outliers, all_z_stats[r, ]) # add line to outliers
    }
}
```

But you could do this without for loop. First, find all the row indices where an entry > 3 is present (using `sapply`. Then, extract only these indices from all_z_stats:

```
outliers <- matrix(ncol=ncol(all_z_stats))
all_z_stats[sapply(seq_len(nrow(all_z_stats)), function(r) any(all_z_stats[r, ] > 3)), ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could define outlier as `numeric()` and use `rbind()` to pile your matrix like this:

```
outliers <- numeric()

for(r in nrow(all_z_stats)){
  for(c in ncol(all_z_stats)){
    if(all_z_stats[r,c]>3){
      outliers <- rbind(outliers,all_z_stats[r,])
      break
    }
  }
}
```

There are better ways to achieve this kind of subsetting.